# Unable to install spaCy on Macbook with arm M1

Tags: python, spacy, apple-m1

### Trying to install spaCy on M1 Mac using pip:

```sh
pip install 'spacy[apple]'
```

### Getting error:

```py
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: remove the quotation marks and probably also the square brackets and try again.

Comment: @D.L If you remove square brackets than pip will try to install x86 version. And quotation required by square brackets syntax.

Comment: seen (in the answer),  thx for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You have to install all dependencies before installing spacy[apple]

###### Install preshed

```
pip install cython 
pip install cymem
pip install murmurhash
pip install preshed
```

###### Install bliss

```
pip install numpy
pip install blis
```

###### Install thinc

```
pip install thinc
```

### And then finally install spaCy:

```
pip install 'spacy[apple]'
```